# How to connect php-fpm with nginx?

Tags: 18.04, php, nginx, php-fpm

I have a server that uses Nginx and PHP-FPM (PHP v7.4). It was working well and I executed the following command for some reasons:

```
apt-get --purge remove php-common
```

After that, I executed this:

```
apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli
```

Commands executed successfully, but I get 502 error when I want to access websites on the servers:

[image: screenshot of 502 error]

It should be noted that there are several projects on this server. And I have nothing inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. I have all configurations under `/etc/nginx/conf.d`. See:

[image]

Each of them is a project. Now, I guess I need to set to PHP-FPM to use `conf.d` instead of `sites-available`. Any idea how can I do that?

Could you please help me how can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure you have reinstalled the required software
specifically the php-fpm

```
sudo apt-get install php-fpm
```

Then start the php fpm as follows

```
sudo systemctl start php7.4-fpm
sudo systemctl enable php7.4-fpm
```

Also make sure the php-fpm is properly setup in the server.conf of nginx. Which as per you must be OK as you havent changed it and it was working before your purge commands

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update `php7.4` to be whatever PHP version is installed.  If you use a custom PHP version, then make sure you use that version string and properly point to wherever its socket runs.